# ¿Por qué este código funciona de esta manera?

Tags: python-3.x, lógica

esta es mi primera consulta en StackOverflow, me encuentro aprendiendo Python y aún estoy muy crudo, pero en un problema random de internet me encontré con lo siguiente:

*Según una lista con números enteros, encontrar cuál número se repite una cantidad impar de veces (solo un único número cumplirá esta condición).*

**Mi primera versión de código fue la siguiente:**

```
example_list = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

unique_list = list(set(example_list))
repetition_list = unique_list

#Primera parte
i = 0
for element in unique_list:
    repetition_list[i] = example_list.count(element)
    i +=1

#Segunda parte
pos = 0
result = None
for element in repetition_list:
    if element%2 !=0:
        result = unique_list[pos]
    pos +=1

print(result)
```

Mi "lógica" fue:

a) Crear dos listas, una lista que contenga los elementos únicos de la lista original (unique_list) y otra que contenga la cantidad de veces que se repiten estos (repetition_list) trabajando con los mismos índices. Cree en esta 2da un clon de la primera a fin de tener una lista con los mismos espacios que luego editaría uno a uno.

b) Determinar la posición de aquel que se repite un número impar de veces de la repetition_list, y luego solo hacer el llamado de unique_list con la misma posición.

Puede no ser la lógica más adecuada, o la mejor forma de trabajarlo, pero mi consulta no radica en cómo hacerlo más eficiente (que igual agradezco sugerencias), mi consulta es:

**¿Por qué se sobreescribe unique_list con los valores de repetition_list?**
Depurando el código me doy cuenta que en el primer for, cada vez que un elemento de repetition_list cambia, el mismo elemento cambia en unique_list (con los mismos valores), tal que al final, en unique_list tengo una copia exacta de repetition_list, y al imprimir finalmente muestra la cantidad impar de veces que se repite dicho número. ¿Por qué pasa esto? Si yo declaré la igualdad de ambas fuera del ciclo for ¿El interprete no lee línea tras línea? ¿Qué no estoy viendo bien?

**Finalmente, dejo la versión de mi código que sí funcionó:**

```
example_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]

unique_list = list(set(example_list))
repetition_list = list()

for element in unique_list:
    repetition_list.append(example_list.count(element))

pos = 0
result = None
for element in repetition_list:
    if element%2 !=0:
        result = unique_list[pos]
    pos +=1

print(result)
```

Remarco que tengo muy poco tiempo aprendiendo de manera autodidacta Python, y entiendo que seguramente no es lo mejor (en lógica y quizás en buenas prácticas), agradezco también cualquier recomendación al respecto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`repetition_list = unique_list` no hace un "clon" como tú dices. Simplemente crea otro "nombre" para la misma lista que tenías en `unique_list`. En python las variables solo son nombres que "apuntan" a objetos (técnicamente se denominan referencias).

En tu primera versión del código solo existe una lista, pero con dos nombres o referencias (`repetition_list` y `unique_list`) así que no es de extrañar que si modificas la lista a través de uno de sus nombres veas la modificación a través del otro.

En tu segunda versión del código `repetition_list` si que es una referencia a una lista independiente, pues la creas de cero y le añades (copias) los elementos.

Otras formas más rápidas de crear una copia de una lista pueden ser:

```
# Usar `list()` para crearla, pero pasarle como parámetro la que quieres copiar
repetition_list = list(unique_list)

# Usar el método `.copy()` que crea una copia de la lista y devuelve esa copia
repetition_list = unique_list.copy()

# Usar un slice. Los slices siempre crean listas nuevas copiando los elementos
# entre los dos índices que indiques, con la sintaxis [inicio:fin]
# Si omites los índices se copia la lista entera
repetition_list = unique_list[:]
```

## Bonus

Al margen de responder tu duda sobre por qué no funcionaba la primera versión, te muestro otra posible forma de resolver el problema, haciendo uso de funciones de utilidad que Python trae de serie y que te pueden ayudar a expresar la solución con muy pocas líneas.

En este caso voy a utilizar la clase `Counter` del módulo `collections`. Esta clase recibe como parámetro una lista y te devuelve un diccionario de contadores. En ese diccionario las claves son los valores (únicos) de la lista y cada clave lleva asociado el contador de cuántas veces se ha repetido ese valor.

Una vez obtenido ese diccionario de contadores es cuestión de iterar por él y quedarse sólo con los valores cuyo contador sea impar, cosa que puedes hacer con una "list comprehension".

El código entonces quedaría simplemente así:

```
from collections import Counter

example_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
resultado = [ valor for valor, contador in Counter(example_list).items() if contador%2 == 1]
print(resultado)
```

Y sale `[4]`

Comment: Me parece muy curioso, ¿Ese comportamiento solo sucede con listas?

Acabo probar este código:

`1) numero_a = 1
2) numero_b = numero_a
3) numero_b = 2

4) print(numero_a)`

Al correr en pantalla muestra: 
1


La lista sí se modifica, pero el valor del primer número queda intacto.

Comment: Ocurre tanto con listas como con números, pero hay un matiz importante. Cuando haces `numero_b=numero_a` de nuevo estás asignando dos "nombres" al 1, pero cuando luego haces `numero_b=2` no estás cambiando el 1 por un 2, sino que estás "reasignando" el nombre numero_b que entonces deja ya de referirse al 1 al que antes se refería para pasar a referirse al 2. Esto ocurre con cualquier asignación de variable, es decir, con cualquier expresión tipo `loquesea = ...`

Comment: Pero fíjate que en las listas, después de hacer `lista_b=lista_a` no reasignas nunca más el nombre `lista_b`, sino que lo utilizas para **acceder a elementos** y son esos elementos los que modificas. Es decir, no haces `lista_b=otra cosa`, sino `lista_b[0] = otra_cosa`. Eso sí modifica el objeto lista al que "apunta" lista_b. Y con un entero en cambio no puedes hacer algo así. No puedes modificar el entero al que apunta, solo puedes hacerle apuntar a otro entero diferente.

Comment: +1 por utilizar la palabra "nombres" para explicar como funciona una variable en Python c:

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es partir con una lista vacía e ir colocando ahí cada valor que no esté presente. Si el valor ya está presente, eliminarlo de la nueva lista. O sea, ir armando y descartando pares.

```
resultado = []
for elemento in lista:
    if elemento in resultado:
        resultado.remove(elemento)
    else:
        resultado.append(elemento)
```

#### Demo

Pondre el código dentro de una función que recibe la lista y retorna una con los impares:

```
def impares(lista):
    resultado = []
    for elemento in lista:
        if elemento in resultado:
            resultado.remove(elemento)
        else:
            resultado.append(elemento)

    return resultado

tests = [
    [1],
    [1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
]

for test in tests:
    resultado = impares(test)
    print(f"{test} -> {resultado}")
```

produce:

```
[1] -> [1]
[1, 1] -> []
[1, 1, 1] -> [1]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3] -> [2]
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1] -> [4]

Process finished with exit code 0
```